# How to add a file and body to MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-restcontroller, mockmvc

Using Spring boot 2 and Spring mvc. I am trying to test my rest controller using `mockMvc`

```
    @PostMapping(
        value = "/attachment")
public ResponseEntity attachment(MultipartHttpServletRequest file, @RequestBody DocumentRequest body) {

    Document document;

    try {

        document = documentService.process(file.getFile("file"), body);

    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());

    }

    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(DocumentUploadSuccess.of(
            document.getId(),
            "Document Uploaded",
            LocalDateTime.now()
    ));

}
```

I could attach the file successfully on my test but know I added a body and I can't receive both attached

```
    @Test
@DisplayName("Upload Document")
public void testController() throws Exception {

    byte[] attachedfile = IOUtils.resourceToByteArray("/request/document-text.txt");

    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "",
            "text/plain", attachedfile);


    DocumentRequest documentRequest = new DocumentRequest();
    documentRequest.setApplicationId("_APP_ID");

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
            MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .fileUpload("/attachment")
                    .file(mockMultipartFile)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(documentRequest));

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(builder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isAccepted())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andReturn();

    JsonNode response = objectMapper.readTree(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

    String id = response.get("id").asText();

    Assert.assertTrue(documentRepository.findById(id).isPresent());

}
```

I got `415` status error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<202> but was:<415>
Expected :202
Actual   :415
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: `.fileUpload()` is [deprecated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#fileUpload-java.net.URI-). Try `.multipart()` instead and add a `contentType()` with the MediaType the controller should receive.

Comment: @Tony thanks about that. Any idea about the other thing?

Comment: Did you try `contentType()` and test it out? Status 415 means unsupported media type which means the mock request you're sending isn't the correct mediaType. Try for example: `.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);`.

Comment: @Tony add your response to select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting status 415: unsupported media type.

You needed to changed add `contentType()` of the request which the controller accepts.
If your controller accepts `application/json`:

```
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .multipart("/attachment")
                        .file(mockMultipartFile)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(documentRequest))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);// <<<
```